# AppleScript saving documents from urls from particular part of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I'm trying to write an AppleScript that saves and downloads all the urls from a particular part of a webpage (a table) and saves them into a folder. All the links are either pdfs or videos that link to Youtube. The table I want to get the links from is organized by week, date and material. I want a folder containing all the weeks, and then inside would be a folder for each date, and another folder that contains the material for that date. (MyStuff/Week/Date/Material)
e.g.

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="topcell">Week </div>
  <div class="topcell">Date</div>
  <div class="topcell">Material</div>
</div>
</div>  <!-- end table-->
```

From some research I've seen that some people are using JavaScript in their implementations to open the document? http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=20287 I tried using something like this but couldn't get it to compile.

I'm completely new at this, so any help would be appreciated! :)

What I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set p1 to path to user/Desktop
    make new folder at p with properties {name:"AllMaterial"}
    --Make AllMaterial Folder--

    set p2 to path to user/Desktop/AllMaterial 
    repeat with i from 1 to 18
        make new folder at p2 with properties {name:"Week" + i}
        --Make all the weeks--

        --in each week, make 3 days--
        set p3 to path3 to user/Desktop/AllMaterial/"Week" + i 
        repeat with j from 1 to 3
            make new folder at p2 with properties {name:"Day" + j}
        end repeat
    end repeat
        --Make all the days--
end

set siteURL to "XXX"

tell application " Safari"
    activate
    open location siteURL
    --wait until page loaded
    if my page_loaded(20) is false then error numner - 128
        set numLinks to (do JavaScript "document.links.length" in document1)
        --(do JavaScript "document.body.table.links.length" in document1)--
        --get num of links --(doesn't account for the "table" that I want ^^. There are multiple     different links on the page )

    set count to numLinks - 1,
    set thisLink to "",
    set f to false
    repeat with i from 0 to count
        set thisLink to do JavaScript
end tell
```

Comment: I suggest you do small steps. First search SO for a a script that gives you the path to an user's folder. (It's all wrong how you do it in above script and will never work)

Answer (score 2):

The question is are you wanting to learn how to do it or are you just wanting someone to provide you a completed script? I can help with the former rather than the later.

To learn how to write the script you need to understand what you trying to achieve and the tools you are using to get the job done.

Three things you must learn, or understand, to solve the problem you are dealing with: Applescript, Javascript and the Document Object Model.

---

**JS & the DOM**

First of all, let's deal with the content and why you can't grab it with Javascript:

```
    <div class="table">
     <div class="row"> 
      <div class="topcell">Week </div>
      <div class="topcell">Date</div>
      <div class="topcell">Material</div>
    </div>
   </div>  <!-- end table-->
```

**This is NOT a table!**

These are divs with classes that are laid out in such a way using CSS to look like a table. Which is why you are having issues navigating the DOM of the page.

```
(do JavaScript "document.body.table.links.length" in document1)--
        --get num of links --(doesn't account for the "table" that I want ^^. There are multiple     different links on the page )
```

**This does not work because there is NO TABLE!**

You need to retrieve the links from the right place. No real table there, each is a div.

I would love to show you a working example, but the 'table' does not contain enough to give a working example. Where exactly are the links?

So, let's make a working example

```
    <div class="table">
     <div class="row"> 
      <div class="topcell">Week</div>
      <div class="example">
       <a href="test">TEST</a>
      </div>
      <div class="topcell">Date</div>
      <div class="topcell">Material</div>
    </div>
   </div>  <!-- end table-->
```

Now we know where the links are, but you need to understand the DOM... 
The following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('example')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
```

would get the href of the first a link of the first element of the document whose class name is example (0 being first in Javascript). We move up to the next a by going to 1:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('example')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[1].href;
```

This is not the method to use for your issue, but is a good example of where you need to head.

You can read more about the navigating the DOM with Javascript [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/traversing-dom) or tons of places, just google it.

---

**Applescript**

The only reason you are using applescript is because you are on a mac... You don't ***need*** to learn applescript to get this done, but it wouldn't hurt.

You do need to learn to do it properly though...Zero is correct, your Applescript is all wrong on many levels...

Small steps, but here is an example of something like how it *should* be

```
tell application "Finder"
    set p1 to (path to desktop folder) as string
    --Make AllMaterial Folder--
    try
        make new folder at p1 with properties {name:"AllMaterial"}
    on error
        --it exists! IT WILL ERROR IF THERE IS A FOLDER ALREADY
    end try

    set p2 to p1 & "AllMaterial" as string
    repeat with i from 1 to 18
        set thisfolder to make new folder at p2 with properties {name:"Week" & i as string}
        --Make all the weeks--
        --in each week, make 3 days--
        repeat with j from 1 to 3
            set thisdaysfolder to make new folder at thisfolder with properties {name:"Day" & j as string}
            ---WHILE IN THIS LOOP thisdaysfolder IS THE REFERENCE TO THE FOLDER TO SAVE IN… SO HERE IS WHERE YOU SAVE TO OR SOME ORDER OR LOGIC...
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

---

**TYING IT TOGETHER**

Bringing it all together to make a complete script depends on the actual data on the website.

The part that grabs the data from the website needs to store the data into applescript lists or possibly grab the data in the repeat when making the folders, etc... it's up to you the coder really.

In the end you need to save the files and you will most likely want to use [cURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/curl.1.html) via shell script and some quoted forms:

```
do shell script "curl -f " & quoted form of thisURL & " -o " & quoted form of (POSIX path of savelocation) & filesname ---(this is a variable with the file name)
```

---

This is not a complete solution obviously but will get you going in the right direction.